# useQuery with post requestr

Tags: axios, react-typescript, react-query

I am developping an interface that uses data that can be filtered with many fields and many values.
The developper working on the backend part has developped an api that returns those data but is using an post api point to be able to handle the numerous filters in the body of the request instead of having a long URL.
I don't know if it a good practise from him but I cannot ask him to change his endpoint.
I am using react query hooks useQuery to get most of the datas in the page that uses get API.
Can I uses this same hook with a post Axios call because when I try it I cannot get the result from the useQuery hooks.

My post API:

```
export const getPostApi = async (
  params: IGridParams,
  inputs: Array<string>,
): Promise<IGridResponse<IData>> => {
  const { limit, page, query, order } = params;
  return AxiosClient.post(
    `${backendUi}/postGetApi?order=${
      order || 'DESC'
    }&page=${page}&take=${limit}${query && `&keyword=${query}`}`,
    {
      filters: [
        {
          field: 'inputs',
          value: inputs
        },
      ],
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem(TOKEN_COOKIE_EM),
      },
    },
  )
    .then(({ data }) => {
      console.log(data);
      return data;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      throw new Error(error);
    });
};
```

This prints my data correctly

My custom hooks:

```
export const useGetPostApi = (
  limit: number,
  page: number,
  query: string,
  inputs: Array<string>,
) => {
  const params: IGridParams = { limit, page, query };
  return useQuery(
    [REACT_QUERY_KEYS.getPost, limit, page, query],
    () => getPostApi(params, inputs),
    { enabled: inputs.length > 0 },
  );
};
```

When called in my component this doesn't returns the data from the API.

Comment: It is hard to tell from your code when code that calls your custom hook `useGetPostApi` is missing. You may want to have a look at this react-query sandbox: https://tanstack.com/query/v3/docs/react/examples/react/custom-hooks

Comment: It was in did a confusion about where my hook is called.
Thanks for your help